# Mysql Return rows which are not repeated from two tables

Tags: mysql

my question is the following:

I have two exact same tables (different names):

```
id, object_id, timestamp, value1, value2
```

I want a query which shows all the values which are in table 1 BUT not in table 2 (all rows in table 2 are in table 1).

Important note: I consider the same row when object_id, timestamp and value1 are the same (id and value2 can be different).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
select a.* from table1 a
left join table2 b
on a.object_id=b.object_id and a.timestamp=b.timestamp and a.value1=b.value1
where b.object_id is null
```

You're creating a left join from one table to the other - so if anything appears in table1 that does not in table 2 will be included.

By adding the where condition you filter for rows where the records exist in table1 but not table2

Comment: Well this may answer the topic starters question.. Your answer is low quality not explaining why this works. This is probably the reason why your answer is voted down.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize one of the things we're expected to do is explain how it works lol - thanks!

Comment: You should use `select a.*`, that way you keep only table1 columns